# How to create custom component in form in C# 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, components

I want to create a custom component in C# and the custom component is going to act as a gauge and consist of a panel with some icons inside it.  Is there a way to create a custom panel component with all of these items inside it and then interact with it all as one component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is called a Usercontrol (or composite control):

- [How to add and create a Usercontrol in Visual Studio 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charles_sterling/archive/2007/12/04/how-to-add-and-create-a-usercontrol-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx) (Says 2008, but everything should also apply to 2010)
- [Walkthrough: Authoring a Composite Control with Visual C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

See also: [Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Forms User Control that Supports Lookup Databinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233787.aspx)

> To create the .NET user control
>
> 1. Create a Visual C# Windows Forms Control Library project named
>      WindowsFormsControlLibrary1:  On the
>      File menu, click New and then click
>      Project. In the Visual C# folder,
>      select Windows Forms Control Library.
>      Accept the WindowsFormsControlLibrary1
>      project name by clicking OK. By
>      default, the name of the .NET control
>      will be UserControl1.
> 2. Add child controls to UserControl1: In the Toolbox, open the All Windows
>      Forms list. Drag a Button control to
>      the UserControl1 design surface. Also
>      add a TextBox control.
> 3. In Solution Explorer, double-click UserControl1.Designer.cs to open it
>      for editing. Change the declarations
>      of the TextBox and the Button from
>      private to public.
> 4. Build the project: On the Build menu, click Build Solution.

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1kyh79x.aspx).